# SSRS Report Field with a Dynamic Data Type

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm amalgamating several manual reports into one  SSRS one by changing the select statements to follow a set format of:

```
 select
 'DepartmentName'
 ,'StatName'
 ,'DataType' --(Int, percentage,date,time, etc)
 ,'Stat'
 from TablesNeeded
```

Now this unions together fine so I end up with a list of statistic names and their values. After this I want to have the cell showing "Stat" to change it's formatting based on the result of "DataType"

I attempted to use an IIF to determine the format, which behaved with a single IIF statement, however after nesting to accomodate different data taypes it appears to "false" every IIF result and return just the default/value:

Working

```
 =iif(
 Fields!DataType.Value="Percentage"
 ,Format(Fields!Stat.Value,"0%")
 ,Fields!Stat.Value
 )
```

"Falsing"

```
 =iif(
 Fields!DataType.Value="Percentage"
 ,Format(Fields!Stat.Value,"0%")
 ,iif(
 Fields!DataType.Value="Date"
 ,Format(Fields!Stat.Value,"y")
 ,iif(
 Fields!DataType.Value="int"
 ,Fields!Stat.Value
 ,Fields!Stat.Value
 )))
```

and using switch similarily also "Falsed"

```
 =Switch(
 Fields!DataType.Value="Percentage",Format(Fields!Stat.Value,"0%")
 ,Fields!DataType.Value="int",Format(Fields!Stat.Value,"#,#0")
 ,Fields!DataType.Value="Date",Format(Fields!Stat.Value,"y")
 )
```

I've asked a colleague and we're both stumped. Any ideas on proper expression formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your datatypes are correct then you just need to use a simplified version of your switch statement in the `Format` property of the cell(s).

Something like..

```
 =SWITCH(
 Fields!DataType.Value="Percentage","0%"
 ,Fields!DataType.Value="int","#,#0"
 ,Fields!DataType.Value="Date","y")
 )
```

Note You could just use "p0" for you percentage type, "n0" for your int.

Comment: Just realised (thought maybe and tried, it worked!) this myself and came here to close off the question. You were spot on though sir!